# load content when scroll over to bottom of window

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I create a program for display hotels when particular location clicked .In this i want to display first 10 hotels and then user scroll to bottom it will display another 10 hotels continously it loads till hotel list ends.
  I need a jquery for this project in which it has two php file.
 1.The first file for load first 10 hotels.
 2. second php file for load balance hotels.

thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need javascript as well.

Comment: whatever javascript or jquery but i need to finish task

Comment: what has this question got to do with Facebook...

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is for asking help with specific problems in existing code, not for making a vague description of a problem in the hopes that someone will write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is [jQuery Infinte Scroll Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).

Answer (score 0):

try using jqgrid and it's virtualscroll feature.